# How to move last two elements of a list to the start in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a list in c# which has the following data,

```
[{"current":"50", "goal":"100", "week":"1"},
{"current":"60", "goal":"100", "week":"2"},
{"current":"45", "goal":"100", "week":"3"},
{"current":"32", "goal":"100", "week":"51"},
{"current":"82", "goal":"100", "week":"52"}]
```

Now I want to bring the last two elements of this list to the start of the list like this,

```
[{"current":"32", "goal":"100", "week":"51"},
{"current":"82", "goal":"100", "week":"52"},
{"current":"50", "goal":"100", "week":"1"},
{"current":"60", "goal":"100", "week":"2"},
{"current":"45", "goal":"100", "week":"3"}]
```

I tried to use RemoveAt and Insert but it is not working.

The following line gives me this error,

```
var item = lst.RemoveAt(3);
```

"Cannot assign void to an implicity-typed local variable"

I understand that the method RemoveAt does not return anything but I need to store the removed elements.

Any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: What is the code you are using, and What do you mean by "not working", exception, error or the list remained unchanged.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a `Queue` instead of a `List`.

Comment: Please show the non-working code where you try using `RemoveAt` and `Insert`.

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: This is actually a great question. The answer in the link above is irrelevant, they're not 'moving' an element, they're recreating one.

Comment: Yes. I do not want to recreate the elements. I just want to move them.

Comment: The problem with that link is that all of the answers remove "Eve" and then put a new "Eve" into the list. A general solution would be more helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use it a lot an extension method sounds like a good approach. You can then move the items from back to front on any generic list.

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static void LastToFront<T>(this List<T> list)
    {
        list.Insert(0, list.Last());
        list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> myList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        myList.LastToFront(); // The result will be { 5, 1, 2, 3, 4 }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Skip method and I got the result,

```
lsttemp = lst.Skip(3).ToList(); 
lst.InsertRange(0, lsttemp); 
lst.RemoveRange(5,2);
```